# Cannot export a 32-bit ServicedComponent from COM+ Catalog using Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 64-bit

Tags: .net, windows, com+, 64-bit

Using Windows 2003 Server or 2000, generating a COM+ application proxy for use on another system, includes .NET Enterprise Services components within the MSI package created during export.  The .NET components are also registered in the GAC and regsvcs runs automatically during installation of the application proxy.

However, we have discovered that Windows Server 2008 does not include the assembly.  It will include the .tlb but not the .dll, nor install it in the GAC, and of course everything blows up when the application cannot find the assembly.

Anyone know what to do to ensure the behaviour works as it does in 2000-2003?

**UPDATE** We can generate a proxy with just the .NET assembly, and it works fine, but if we try to add other assemblies or legacy VB6 COM+ dlls to the same package it says they were built for a different processor.

**UPDATE** I understand that if you build in Any CPU mode (which all projects are set to), then when you register by dropping your assemblies into the Component Services application, it will use 64 bit if it's an existing 64-bit application.  However, this is a 32-bit application.  There are VB6 dlls that are registered in the COM+ application, which are 32-bit.  So that should use the 32-bit registry etc..., and cause the application to be 32-bit.  So when a .NET Any CPU assembly is added after, it should be 32-bit ... however when we export the application the .NET assembly doesn't get added to the .MSI which is created.

**UPDATE** We have found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924729 which discusses a bug where 32-bit ServicedComponents cannot be exported ... there is a hotfix, but it is for Windows Server 2003.  We have narrowed the problem down and it's only 32-bit ServicedComponents that are not exporting properly.

Comment: Is your Server 2008 x64?

Comment: Yes.  I've updated my question with a bit more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS has hotfix for this issue for 2008r2.  We were able to get them to confirm it as a bug and release a hotfix last year.  Try contacting them to get the HF.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Unfortunately, it's way too late for that project. :)

Answer (score 3):

.NET dlls compiled to any cpu will take on a bitness when they are jit compiled.  COM+ only has a sense of hard bitness.  x86 OR x64, but not neutral.  For this reason, you need to use one of the two and not Any CPU.

Earl

Answer (score 1):

I have been in contact with Microsoft technical support about this.  The problem is that you cannot export ANY 32-bit ServicedComponent from COM+ applications, properly, on Windows 2008 64-bit, because of the way the registry and catalog have changed.  This was a problem on Windows Server 2003 as well, but was fixed by a hotfix, and was marked as fixed in Windows Server 2008 64-bit, but actually was NOT fixed in 2008.  This is also a bug in Windows 7.

All Windows 7 developers who care about this issue should contact Microsoft technical support to report that they are experiencing this issue, as Microsoft has no intention of fixing this without a cost justification from a customer.  We are in the process of trying to get MS to accept our business case as justification.  I will update this post in the future if anything changes.

Comment: Microsoft has said it is not going to fix this issue.

Comment: So what is the resolution? I am trying to export to a 32bit machine a com+ export generated on 2008 R2 64bit and it isn't working. Can I create the details myself?

Comment: @JonH As I said, Microsoft will not fix this issue.  There is no resolution, so you have to find another way.

Comment: Blooming M$! I actually found that following the steps in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4140614/711437 side-stepped this issue for me.

Comment: @JonH Glad it worked for you, in our case we were totally stuck and had to port the legacy code.