# 64bit Component COM+ export running on 32bit machine

Tags: .net, com, 64-bit, 32-bit, cpu-architecture

I have an C# application written to install as a Enterprise Component Service (that uses WCF .NET etc) I have tested this and it works on both 32bit and 64bit.

I am now trying to export a COM+ stub proxy from the 64bit machine to run on a 32bit machine using 64bit as the activation server.

It doesn't work. The installer reports that the application does not support the processor type.

What are my options here? 
Is it possible to export using a 32bit version of component services? 
Is it possible to create the proxy manually on the target machine?
Or is this simply impossible and I need to rebuild the target machine as 32bit?

Thanks muchly!

Comment: What command line are you using to do the export?

Comment: I am using Component Services export, I have also tried the C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64>mmc comexp.msc /32

Comment: Found a way around this... followed this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4140614/711437

Answer (score 0):

When you register the application you need to use the 32 bit version of regsvcs, so when you export the proxies the result will run on 32 bit machine.

Or you will need to create a custom installer for the proxy.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2741982?wa=wsignin1.0